# What's the best way to manage connection failures (and reconnection) to a mongodb replica set in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm using a replica set in mongo, one of the clients connecting to the set is a Rails app using MongoMapper as object mapper. I want to make sure in case I receive a Mongo::ConnectionFailure because something went wrong with one of the nodes it will reconnect properly, the official Mongodb documents state that it is the responsibility of the client to [rescue/reconnect](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.REPLICA_SETS.html#Connection_Failures).

Now, I could just add a rescue block as an around filter, but that hardly seems like a good solution ( not the controllers reponsability for sure).

What would be a good place to rescue/reconnect short of adding it to MongoMapper?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a tough problem. You can get this error for a bunch of reasons.

1. The replica set is completely unavailable.
2. The `mongos` process is unavailable (in sharded configs)
3. The replica set is in the process of electing a new primary.

Ideally, #3 is the most common cause.

In the case of #3, you can catch the exception, wait a second and retry. You may need to retry a few times before you give up (what if it's #1?)

So the case you typically want to handle is a change in primaries which generally takes a few seconds. However, you can't wait forever so you still have to be able to handle a "failure" after some number of seconds.

This exception handling code probably belongs somewhere in the **MongoMapper** code. And hey it's OSS, so that can be done. But recognize that there are several potential reasons for a connection failure, so even the example in the docs may not be sufficient.

When using replica sets, you'll also want to consider your [write concern](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.WRITE_CONCERN.html). These can also throw exceptions, including some form of "not master" exception which probably requires some special log as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I agree the best place to add any code would be MM however I'm not running a sharded mongo, and in the end 3 and 1 are the same for the point of view of the clients, I mean whether the set chose a new primary or it is gone the clients should keep trying to reconnect or is there something in there that should be dealt with differently?

Comment: So the question is really about what the client expects to receive. There's a difference between *"we could not access the DB for 5 seconds"* and *"we cannot access the DB at all"*. Also many clients would rather just wait a few seconds instead of receiving the error. But you can't wait forever. So you have to balance "retry the query" with "send error to client".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know MongoMapper uses the mongodb driver, which does not reconnect. 
You probably should use Mongoid, that have that feature than.